# Unexpected status line: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Tags: android, http, url, jsoup, okhttp

I wanted to fetch and parse specific web site: http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html using Android & Kotlin
Problem makes HTML 4.01(ISO 8879) where any of techniques(Jsoup, okhttp. url.readText...) gives same error.

I tried almost everything I found on internet plus thousand of my ideas, non of them worked. I tried with Jsoup, Okhttp, URL..

This are just a few unsuccesfull tries(tried one by one, sorry about mess)...

```
         try {
        val url =URL( "http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html")
       /*val con =Jsoup.connect("http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html").followRedirects(true)
     val resp = con.execute().method(Connection.Method.GET)*/
 //  val completeFile = resp.body()
      //  val doc = resp.parse()


       // val doc = Jsoup.parse(URL("http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html"), 2000)
       // val doc  = Jsoup.connect("http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html").get()
        //val doc = Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.connect("http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get().html())
       /* val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        val text = urlConnection.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()*/

        val okHtttClient = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

        val response = okHtttClient.newCall(request).execute()
```

It would mean a lot if someone tries to access url written above, cos I'm still not shure why I'm getting this error. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: So I wanted to parse web site using Jsoup. Problem is first line in source code of html, where I get error on connection execute. I also have tried OkHttp, URL, and HTTP. 
This is the web site I need to fetch: http://trafo2.fesb.hr/index.html 
Web site uses HTML 4.01 which gives me an error. 
 If you could try to connect and let me know. This is Android+Kotlin, thanks in advance.